# Using only agregate function on determined row

Tags: mysql

I have to use only aggregate function (so without checking exact values in columns, for determined row), when I select the determined IT worker's salary.
It isn't as simple as `SELECT SUM(salary) FROM table WHERE occupation='IT worker' LIMIT <here stays which place the person has on the list>, 1`, is it? I think that by using `SUM` command, we don't check exact values.

If this question isn't understandable, I can translate the whole exercise.

EDIT: the exercise
Using only agregate functions (without checking exact values in columns, for determined row) create a query, which lets us know about determined IT worker's salary. `table` contains:
`id int`
`occupation varchar(50)`
`salary int`

Comment: The select statement is a sum over all it workers not individual workers in it - if that's what you want it's fine if not you will have to be a bit clearer on what you do want.

Comment: Limit will just "limit" the output to the number of rows you specify. If the result matches 4 rows but you set limit 1, it will return only thr first one of those 4. It is convinient when you know the result is one or when you don't want more than one row affected if something goes wrong.

Comment: I attached exercise to my post

Comment: 'know about determined IT worker's salary' is too vague what is it you want to know about - do you want to know if it workers salary  >= avg salary, where it worker sits in the salary league table or some other thing(s).

Comment: I can't translate this part in the other way, I have difficulty understading it, I suppose that we know that Adam Jonhson is an IT Worker and we want to know his salary, but the condition between brackets is confusing me

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the queries, this is meant to get you started:

The table seems to have 3 fields: id, occupation, and salary.
Each row seems to correspond to a specific worker

Then you can use agregate functions to calculate stuff regarding different occupations (for example).

The structure for a query that uses agregate functions is like this:

```
Select <fields and agregate functions>  
from table  
where <filter records to consider for the query before aggregation>  
group by <field having the same value, hence that can be grouped by>  
having <optional condition evaluated after doing the aggregation>
```

Examples of agregate functions are Sum, Count, Avg.

The question is not clear but with the informatin you have you can calculate:

Number of workers with same occupaton.
Average salary.
Total salary income by occupation.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore department for now you could do something like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select emp_no, salary from employees ;
+--------+--------+
| emp_no | salary |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |  20000 |
|      2 |  39500 |
|      3 |  50000 |
|      4 |  19500 |
|      5 |  10000 |
|      6 |  19500 |
|      7 |  40000 |
|      9 |   NULL |
+--------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>  select emp_no,salary,
    ->  concat(rank,' of ' ,obs) as Rank,
    ->  Position,
    ->  reltoavg realtivetoavg
    ->   from
    ->  (
    ->  select emp_no,salary ,
    ->  @rn:=@rn+1 as Rank,
    ->  (select count(*) from employees) as obs,
    ->  concat('There are ',
    ->  (Select count(*) from employees e1 where e1.SALARY > e.salary) , ' employees who earn more and ',
    ->  (Select count(*) from employees e1 where e1.SALARY < e.salary and salary is not null) ,  ' who earn less') Position,
    ->  (select avg(salary) from employees) avgsalary,
    ->  if (salary > (select avg(salary) from employees), 'Salary is above average', 'salary is below average') reltoavg
    ->  from employees e,(Select @rn:=0) r
    ->  where salary is not null
    ->  order by salary
    ->  ) s
    ->  where s.emp_no = 1
    ->  ;
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| emp_no | salary | Rank   | Position                                                | realtivetoavg           |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|      1 |  20000 | 4 of 8 | There are 3 employees who earn more and 3 who earn less | salary is below average |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```